# 2 Buttons but just one work in wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I want to insert 2 Buttons in my C# Project. But just one of them works. I Tried different things, and i noticed in the second button script `BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />` is a `/>` i think this is the problem. But at the time i remove it `/` convert it to a `>` it gives me an error out.

But heres the code, maybe you can help:

*Edit: Code is to long so heres a Link: http://pastebin.com/MysA7Dh1 
**Edit: First a big Thanks for the Help :)! And i dont want you to do the work for me but i dont find an solution. The first button just looks like the second on the xaml code for me. 
But now i can click the button but this time i dont see the image. I see it on the first button but not on the second.

Updated code: http://pastebin.com/PZhtssSy

nvm i set the Margin wrong. :/

Comment: What does not work with your second button? Just "does not work" doesn't tell us anything. You mention "gives me an error out". What error? Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to include that image inside the button code?  Or is the image supposed to be separate?

If you're trying to include the image inside the button, your code should look like this (code overly simplified for clarity):

```
<Button>
    <Image/>
</Button>
```

If they are supposed to be separate:

```
<Button />
<Image />
```

Comment: I think @Cedric forgots the closing </Button>-Tag, so your answer should solve the Problem.